# Nginx configuration example for sockJS-tornado

Tags: websocket, tornado, sockjs

I need tornado-sockJS Nginx configuration i cant find any documentation on the web who can help me?

not working  tornado-nginx configurations with sockJS ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use SockJS-Tornado in my blog application. I create a SockJSRouter [in my code here](https://github.com/ajdavis/motor-blog/blob/master/motor_blog/application.py#L21). My SockJSConnection subclass [is defined in my code here](https://github.com/ajdavis/motor-blog/blob/master/motor_blog/web/admin.py#L210), and [here is my nginx.conf](https://github.com/ajdavis/motor-blog/blob/master/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.example). The relevant lines of my nginx.conf are like:

```
location /blog/sock_js {
    proxy_pass http://motor_blog;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```